# how to handle lots of separate ui commands c#, how to get them, initialize them and execute them

Tags: c#, command, builder, fluent

I have fairly complicated ui system that i want to simplify. What I want is to make separate classes with command and fluent builder pattern that which instances I will create at the beginning of the app and then execute when needed, something like this:

```
public interface IGuiCommand
{
  void Execute();
  void Execute(Action onComplete = null);
}

public class GuiCommandBuilder : IGuiCommand
{
  public void Execute()
  {

  }

  public void Execute(Action onComplete = null)
  {
  }
}

public class GuiCommandTest : GuiCommandBuilder
{
  private int _id;
        
  public GuiCommandTest()
  {
            
  }

  public GuiCommandTest Setup(int id)
  {
    _id = id;
    return this;
  }
}
```

so I can do this:

```
// create command
var GuiRoomSelectionCommand = new GuiCommandTest();

// setup and execute (I have to provide additional data in order
// command to work correctly, some commands don't need additional data)
GuiRoomSelectionCommand
  .Setup(223)
  .Execute(() =>
  {

  });
```

The problem I am having is that I want to create all commands
at the start of the app and store them for later easy access, but I can't just
store them as IGuiCommand since I will need a concrete instance in order to setup the
concrete commands? How to do that, or if any other setup is better approach?

I want that others can easily see what commands are there and how to add more of them
if needed or easily modify the existing ones in separate classes so that main controller
doesn't change to much but only specific commands

Comment: Why create all commands upfront? Why not create them when they are needed? You could make them `struct`s if heap allocations are a concern.

Comment: Also note that the builder pattern is for optional/additional data, but not for required data. That's what constructors and factory methods are for.

Answer (score 0):

Define an `ICommandParameter` interface to indicate the name of the parameter and its current value.

You can create different types of parameters by implementing this interface:

```
public ICommandParameter
{
    string Name {get;set;}
    object ObjectValue {get;set;}
}

public IDoubleParameter : ICommandParameter
{
    double MinValue {get;set;}
    double MaxValue {get;set;}
    double Number {get;set;}
    int DecimalsCount {get;set;}
}

public IBoolParameter : ICommandParameter
{
    bool Checked {get;set;}
}

public IAnimalsParameter : ICommandParameter
{
    Animal Animal {get;set;} // Animal is an enum with a list of values
}
```

Now, your `IGuiCommand` can have a list of `ICommandParameter` that you can initialize in the constructor of your command.

In `GuiCommandBuilder` (or in other class if you consider) you can manage the parameters. You have access to the command parameters and show/update using some Forms.

For example, in your `GuiRoomSelectionCommand` you can access to the parameters list, with a simgle parameter "Number of rooms" that you can see (you can check/try cast) that implements `IDoubleParameter` with this values:

```
Name = "Number of rooms"
ObjectValue = 2
MinValue = 1
MaxValue = 10
Number = 2 // Usually a cast of ObjectValue interface
DecimalsCount = 0
```

You can create a Form in which you add some controls depending of parameters type. For previous example, you can add a `Label` for `Name` and a `NumericUpDown` for the value (settings decimals, minimum and maximum). You initialize the numeric with the `Number` property. And when you click Ok in the dialog, you can update de `Number` property with the numeric value.

For any Enum property, you can add a ComboBox to show/edit it's value. For a `bool` property, a `CheckBox` and so on.

You need spend some time to create the controls for any type of property to manage but, at the end, most of properies are of basic types. There aren't lots of controls.